# Continuous Fibonacci number F(n)

Tags: sequences-and-series, fibonacci-numbers

How is a continuous Fibonacci number $F_n$ defined? (like the Gamma function for factorials)

Tried with Binet's formula (Wiki) , but to no luck.

```
F[n_] = N[GoldenRatio^n - 1/GoldenRatio^n]/Sqrt[5]
Plot[F[n], {n, 3., 12.}, GridLines -> Automatic]
FibonRatio[n_] = N[Fibonacci[n + 1]/Fibonacci[n]];
Plot[{FibonRatio[n], N[GoldenRatio], 1.7}, {n, 3., 12.}, 
 GridLines -> Automatic]
```

Also using this continuous function definition how is it proved that

$$\lim _{n\rightarrow \infty}\dfrac{F_{n+1}}{F_n} = \phi$$

( where $\phi$ is the GoldenRatio) ?

Appreciate your comments.

Comment: Does your software let you calculate the correct $F_n$ for integers $n\ge0$? If so, the most likely issues with ratios are returning an integer quotient and making $n$ so large the numerator and denominator too large to work with. But a formula for $F_{n+1}/F_n$ can get around that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$F_n=\frac{\phi^n-\cos(\pi n)\phi^{-n}}{\sqrt{5}},$ with $\phi$ being the golden ratio. Here $n$ can be also complex.

You can also rewrite the ratio as
$$\frac{F_{n+1}}{F_n}=\phi\left(\frac{1+(-1)^{n+1}\phi^{-2(n+1)}}{1+(-1)^{n+1}\phi^{-2n}}\right),$$
where it easier to show that the ratio converges to $\phi$ and maybe you like it for calculations. But for the proof only I would rather prefer the other answers to be honest.

Comment: How to derive the formula $ \displaystyle F_n=\frac{\phi^n-\cos(\pi n)\phi^{-n}}{\sqrt{5}}$?

Answer (score 3):

Since you are using *Mathematica*, judging by the code in the OP, you can easily obtain the actual expression used by *Mathematica* for evaluating Fibonacci numbers of non-integer index:

```
FunctionExpand[Fibonacci[n]]
   ((1/2 (1 + Sqrt[5]))^n - (2/(1 + Sqrt[5]))^n Cos[n π])/Sqrt[5]
```

In more conventional notation ($\phi$ is the golden ratio, as usual):

$$F_n=\frac{\phi ^n-\phi ^{-n} \cos (\pi  n)}{\sqrt{5}}$$

(This is also the expression given in the [Wolfram Functions site](https://functions.wolfram.com/IntegerFunctions/Fibonacci/02/0001/) and CostaZach's answer.)

This of course doesn't imply that this is the only way to define the Fibonacci numbers for non-integer index. For instance, [this function](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/BinetFibonacci) uses

$$f_n=\frac{(1 + \sqrt{5})^n - (1 - \sqrt{5})^n}{2^n\sqrt{5}}$$

but unlike the previous formula, this becomes complex-valued in general for real non-integer argument.

Comment: Yes, actually sir, it was my  error after watching a late night video illustrating natural geometric patterns  e.g.,observed  in helical patterns  of Sunflower seed packings possible only between neighboring $F_n$. For large $n$ we see  strong tendency towards two strangely asymmetric *logarithmic*  spirals.

Comment: How to derive the formula $\displaystyle F_n=\frac{\phi^n-\cos(\pi n)\phi^{-n}}{\sqrt{5}}$ ?

Answer (score 2):

$\DeclareMathOperator{\bbN}{\mathbb{N}}$$\newcommand{\digsum}{\text{digitsum}} \DeclareMathOperator{\bbO}{\mathbb{O}} \DeclareMathOperator{\bbE}{\mathbb{E}}$$\blacksquare$ **Notation:** Let us denote:

- $\bbO := $ the set of all odd natural numbe\rs
- $\bbE := $ the set of all even natural numbers

---

**Hint:** Let $F_0 = 0$ and $F_1 = 1$. We can see the following:
$$ F_{n + 1} = F_{n} + F_{n - 1} \quad \text{for } n \geqslant 1  $$
$$ \implies \frac{F_{n + 1}}{F_n} = 1 + \frac{F_{n-1}}{F_n} = 1 + \frac{1}{\frac{F_{n}}{F_{n - 1}}} = 1 + \frac{1}{1 + \frac{F_{n-2}}{F_{n - 1}}} = \cdots = 1 + 
\frac{1}{1 + \frac{1}{ 1 + \frac{1}{1 + \frac{1}{1 + \cdots (n\text{ times})}}}} $$

---

**Lemma 1:** The sequence $\{ \xi_n\}_{n=1}^\infty := \left\{ \dfrac{F_{n + 1}}{F_n} \right\}_{n = 1}^\infty$ has the following properties:

- The even subsequence $\{ \xi_{2k}\}_{k=1}^\infty := \left\{ \dfrac{F_{2k + 1}}{F_{2k}} \right\}_{k = 1}^\infty$ increases.
- The odd subsequence $\{ \xi_{2k + 1}\}_{k=0}^\infty := \left\{ \dfrac{F_{2k + 2}}{F_{2k + 1}} \right\}_{k = 0}^\infty$ decreases.

*Proof:* The proof will be immediate from the relation $~F_{n}^2 + (-1)^n = F_{n + 1}F_{n - 1}  ~$ for any $n \geqslant 1$ [prove it using induction].

Now we have that $$ \xi_{n+1} - \xi_n = \frac{F_{n + 1}}{F_n} - \frac{F_n}{F_{n - 1}} = \frac{F_{n +1}F_{n - 1} - F_n^2 }{F_n F_{n - 1}} = \frac{(-1)^n}{F_nF_{n - 1}}  \begin{cases} >0 & \text{if } n \in \bbE\\ < 0 & \text{if } n \in \bbO  \end{cases}  $$
Thus we proved our claim. $\hspace{14cm} \blacksquare$

---

**Lemma 2:** The sequence $\{ \xi_n\}_{n = 1}^\infty$ is bounded.

*Proof:* We know that $\{ F_n\}_{n = 0}^\infty$ is an increasing sequence. Note that $$ F_{n + 1} = F_{n} +F_{n - 1} \implies \xi_n = 1 + \frac{F_{n - 1}}{F_n} < 1 + 1 = 2 $$
And trivially $ 0 < \xi_n < 2 ~$ for all $n \in \bbN$

Thus we have that $$0 <\frac{F_{n+1}}{F_{n}} <  {2}  $$
Hence it's bounded. $\hspace{15cm} \blacksquare$

---

**Lemma 3:** The following holds:
$$ \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{F_{n + 1}}{F_n} ~\text{  exists } $$
*Proof:* Follows from **Lemma 1** and **Lemma 2** $\hspace{7cm} \blacksquare$

So, let's observe that $$\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \frac{F_{n + 1}}{F_n } = L  = 1 + 
\frac{1}{1 + \frac{1}{ 1 + \frac{1}{1 + \frac{1}{1 + \cdots (\infty\text{ times})}}}} = \frac{1}{1 + L} $$
$$ \implies L^2 - L - 1 = 0 \implies L = \frac{1 + \sqrt{5}}{2} = \phi $$

Comment: Nice continuous fraction result. But I am looking to prove using a continuous function definition.

Comment: Can you please explain what do you want as proof using a continuous function definition? It'll help me : )

Comment: Sorry. Binet formula was ok as  later realized !

Comment: I'll edit the post and make it an elaborate and elementary solution. Please check it out too :)

Comment: Your answer is great. Actually I was imagining a single numerator/denominator situation whose limit could be evaluated at $n\rightarrow \infty$.

Comment: Just wait for some time. I'll elaborate it :)

Answer (score 1):

Suppose we have a sequence $\{ a_n \}_{n \geq 1}$ obeying a linear recurrence of the form $$a_n = p a_{n-1} + q a_{n-2}$$ for some constants $p, q$. Then if the *characteristic equation* $$\lambda^2 = p \lambda + q$$ has distinct roots, then [every solution to the recurrence is of the form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_relation#Solving_homogeneous_linear_recurrence_relations_with_constant_coefficients) $$a_n = c_1 \lambda_1^n + c_2 \lambda_2^n,$$ where $\lambda_1, \lambda_2$ are the two roots of the characteristic equation, and $c_1, c_2$ are constants chosen to match initial conditions on the sequence (usually, specified values of $a_1$ and $a_2$).

In the case of the Fibonacci sequence, the recurrence is $a_n = a_{n-1} + a_{n-2}$, with initial conditions $a_1 = a_2 = 1$. The characteristic equation is $\lambda^2 = \lambda + 1$, with roots $\lambda = \frac{1 \pm \sqrt{5}}{2}$.

Writing $\lambda_1 = \phi = \frac{1 + \sqrt{5}}{2} \approx 1.618...$, the other root is $\lambda_2 = -1/\phi = \frac{1 - \sqrt{5}}{2} \approx -0.618...$, and the constants $c_1, c_2$ making $a_1 = a_2 = 1$ are $c_1 = 1/\sqrt{5}, c_2 = -1/\sqrt{5}$. From this we find the formula, valid for all $n \geq 1$, $$a_n = F_n = \frac{\phi^n - (-\phi)^{-n}}{\sqrt{5}},$$ and one desired continuous extension is clearly the real part $$F_x = \Re(\frac{\phi^x - (-\phi)^{-x}}{\sqrt{5}}).$$

For large values of $x$, the $\phi^{-x}$ term (which is also the source of the imaginary part) tends to zero, so $F_x \approx \phi^x/\sqrt{5}$, from which we easily derive $$\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{F_{x+1}}{F_x} = \phi.$$

Comment: $\lambda_2$ is not equal to $1/\phi$, but to $-1/\phi$

Comment: @jjagmath Good catch, just fixed it!

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason you aren't able to get a continuous graph when plotting the binet is because the $\left(\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^n$ term is unreal for most noninteger values of $n$.

I don't think there exists any continuous formula for the Fibonacci Sequence, but $\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}\left(\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^{x}+\left(\frac{\sqrt{5}-1}{2}\right)^{x}\right)$ and $\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}\left(\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^{x}-\left(\frac{\sqrt{5}-1}{2}\right)^{x}\right)$ are both good continuous approximations and are exact for odd and even terms respectively.

A less rigorous approach for proving the limit of the ratio of subsequent terms is to note that for $x>>1$ $F_n\approx \frac{\phi^n}{\sqrt{5}}$. So as $x\to\infty$, $\frac{F_{n+1}}{F_n}\to \frac{\phi^{n+1}}{\phi^n}=\phi$