How to express the approximate CURVE of the Fibonacci sequence in a function?
Is there a way to derive a curve function for the Fibonacci sequence to plot an approximation of the increase in value for each iteration?
Please bear with me if I'm using the wrong terminology when describing some of these concepts. I'm not coming from a "math background".
Maybe a visual aid is the most efficient way to explain:

First, some considerations to acknowledge:

My reference image uses a Bézier curve, as can be observed from the handles on many of the points. It is not derived from any kind of formula. I just eyeballed the angles of the handles.
Not all graph points have a corresponding Bézier handle point. This was done to beautify the curve, as it looks smoother this way.
My Fib sequence begins with 1, not 0. People can debate which is technically correct, but for the purpose of this application, I want a smooth ease-in curve, and beginning from 1 gives that.
The first few iterations of the Fibonacci sequence have values so small that they deviate from the curve trend but since they are required to be integers, they are what they are.
For all I know, there could be an entire area of mathematics dedicated to the approximation of curves, and maybe people are doing this kind of thing all the time - I just don't know about it.
I know there is a close relationship between the Fibonacci sequence and Phi. For example, a Fibonacci spiral and a Phi spiral are very similar, but not exactly the same. Anyone with insights about the correlation within the context of this question, please share.

 src
The curve I've approximated is fine for many purposes, but it is purely aesthetic. This curve is not mathematical in any meaningful or precise way. On the other hand, if we try to make it conform exactly to each incremental value of the Fibonacci sequence, the first few iterations produce a curve that is not "ease-in" in the pure sense - that is to say it would have a bumpy start.
So (to put it another way) is there a way to produce a curve close to this that is mathematically derived?
There could be benefits to having a function for such an ease-in curve that also mostly (not counting the first few iterations) conforms to the curve of the Fib. seq.
For example, knowing that any point on that curve can be plotted, we could get the Fibonacci-like approximated value for not only integers (iteration 8 = 21), but also decimals along that curve (iteration 7.36 = 12.685), for example. (The example is a rough approximation, of course.)
It could be useful in programming as well, to have the curve available as a function.

Edit: I have just noticed that if not requiring that one Bez handle point lie on the first 1, we can begin the sequence from 0 and that actually looks a little more correct:

Either way, regardless of how we decide we want to approximate the curve, the nature of the question remains the same: Is there a way to do it by formula?

See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3821443/continuous-fibonacci-number-fn

$F(x)=\frac{\varphi^x - (1-\varphi)^x}{\sqrt{5}}$

@mira666 That function doesn't take real values. For example, $F(1/2)\not\in \Bbb R$

The expression
$$
f(x)=\Re\left( \dfrac{\phi^x - (1-\phi)^x}{\sqrt{5}}\right),
$$
where $\phi = \frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$, coincides with the Fibonacci sequence when $x \in \mathbb{N}$. This is not very meaningful/useful but does the trick.
The graphs below represent the real and imaginary parts of $\dfrac{\phi^x - (1-\phi)^x}{\sqrt{5}}$.



Thank you! I think that since the early iterations are not smooth, one approach if wanting a smooth ease-in could be to use a simple curve for the first 5 or so iterations, and as it ramps up, interpolate into the accurate Fibonacci-coinciding curve that you derived. I realize my question is unusual because I asked about a mathematically accurate representation while also stating that I want a smooth ease-in, so a compromise that blends the two is probably the only way of meeting both goals.
